# java.rmi.UnmarshalException while deploying in weblogic

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, weblogic12c

I'm getting the below exception while deploying the application in weblogic server:

```
[java] weblogic.management.jmx.RemoteRuntimeException: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal class java.lang.Object;
```

nested exception is:

```
[java]     java.io.InvalidClassException: 
javax.servlet.ServletException; local class incompatible: 
stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4221302886851315160, 
local class serialVersionUID = 205441063386195800
```

I have a servlet with init method as shown below.
 Initially it had the `setPreLoginURIMapper` method alone and it was working fine
 Now I added a new method `setForgotPasswordOverlayURIMapper` which does almost the same function as the `setPreLoginURIMapper` other than that it reads another set of init params from the *web.xml*
 The new init param added in web.xml is also given below.

Any thoughts?

```
public void init(HttpServlet servletArg) throws ServletException
{
    super.init(servletArg);
    setPreLoginURIMapper(servletArg);
    //Added newly
    setForgotPasswordOverlayURIMapper(servletArg);
    return;
}

private void setForgotPasswordOverlayURIMapper(HttpServlet servletArg) throws ServletException
    {
        String propsStr = getNotEmptyParam(servletArg, ForgotPasswordOverlayURIMapperParam_);
        TokenizedProperties props = TokenizedProperties.getInstance(propsStr, ITEM_DELIMITERS, ASSIGNMENT_DELIMITERS);
        forgotPasswordOverlayURIMapper_ = getValidPreLoginURIMapper(props, servletArg.getServletName());
        return;
    }
```

New entry in *web.xml* is as shown below:

```
<init-param>
       <description>the URI for password overlay</description>
       <param-name>ForgotPasswordOverlayURIMapper</param-name>
       <param-value>
        member=/security/member/inputFPUsername.ndo;
        provider=/security/provider/inputFPUsername.ndo;
        employer=/security/employer/inputFPUsername.ndo;
        broker=/security/broker/inputFPUsername.ndo
        shopping=/security/shopping/inputFPUsername.ndo
       </param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: Didn't find a solution yet. As a workaround, added init params in the existing entry itself.